# Почему при использовании AngularJS перестает работать jQuery?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Страница состоит из двух блоков: список всех элементов и создание нового элемента. Создание нового сделал с использованием jquery.steps. Работало хорошо.
Далее добавил angular и директиву ng-switch. Angular заработал, перестал работать steps. Странность еще в том, что если сделать форму выбором по умолчанию (в скрипте selection = 'new'), то и steps начинает работать, а если по человечески, сначала список, а по нажатию на кнопку новый - ломается.

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="selection" />
<div ng-switch on="selection">
    <div class="new" ng-switch-when="new">
        <form id="formwizard">
        <!--тут форма-->
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="all" ng-switch-when="all">
    <!--тут список-->
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var form = $('#formwizard').show();
        form.steps({
            headerTag: 'h3',
            bodyTag: 'fieldset',
            transitionEffect: 'slideLeft'
        });
    });

    var testApp = angular.module('testApp');
    testApp.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = ['all', 'new'];
        $scope.selected = $scope.items[0];

        $scope.createNew = function () {
            $scope.selected = $scope.items[1];
        }
        $scope.showAll = function () {
            $scope.selected = $scope.items[0];
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: потому что не надо одновременно использовать и то и то

Comment: @Grundy а почему? с плагинами же лучше, чем без плагинов

Comment: как видно - с плагинами не работает :) поэтому точно не лучше ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) как и [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) - удаляют полностью элементы из разметки, поэтому элемент form на который ты инициализируешь плагин у тебя то появляется до того как идет вызов `form.steps`, в этом случае до переключения switch все работает, то *не* появляется, в этом случае ничего не работает.

Решений может быть несолько:

1. отказаться от отдельного плагина jQuery и найти аналог в анугляре
2. поместить вызов плагина в [отдельную директиву](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) и в ней отслеживать изменения, чтобы переинициализировать плагин
3. в самом контроллере переинициализировать плагин с задержкой, чтобы во view успел отрисоваться нужный элемент (самый плохой вариант)
4. Отказаться от использования ng-if/switch и заменить их на ng-show/hide, так как данные директивы только меняют style:display, но не убирают элемент из разметки.
5. Если сделать директиву для тега form, то отслеживать ничего не надо, так как функция link будет вызываться каждый раз при добавлении элемента.

---

Пример директивы:

```
.directive('formSteps',function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope,elem){
        elem.steps({
            headerTag: 'h3',
            bodyTag: 'fieldset',
            transitionEffect: 'slideLeft'
        });
    }
  }
})
```

Разметка при этом будет выглядеть так:

```
<form id="formwizard" form-steps>
```

И в коде часть

```
$(function () {
    var form = $('#formwizard').show();
    form.steps({
        headerTag: 'h3',
        bodyTag: 'fieldset',
        transitionEffect: 'slideLeft'
    });
});
```

уже не нужна.

Comment: А можно какой-нибудь пример, как реализовать второй сценарий?

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев, лучше для первого поискать. сделай [mcve] чтобы можно было запустить

Comment: Не надо отслеживать изменения и переинициализировать плагин в таком простмо случае :) Достаточно просто вызывать плагин в конструкторе директивы и *не* использовать ng-if/switch внутри формы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, это четвертый вариант, фактически заключается в отказе от  ng-if/switch и заменой на ng-show/hide :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov окей, как вызвать плагин из директивы?

Comment: @Grundy нет, это я второй уточняю. И да, четвертый тоже стоило бы написать.

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев а в чем, собственно, проблема?

Comment: @PavelMayorov 0.0 скиллов в директивах ангуляра

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев, [Директивы](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), [Компоненты](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, добавил 4. но не понял почему это уточнение ко второму были. Второй вполне самостоятельный

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев а при чем тут плагин?

Comment: @Grundy я не предлагал отказываться от ng-if *снаружи*. Я лишь написал, что если не использовать структурные директивы *внутри* - отслеживание изменений не понадобится.

Comment: ng-show/hide подойдут только для случая с двумя блоками, на три уже нет

Comment: не пойму, в чем проблема привести пример кода с директивой, вызывающей steps для элемента form, для этого обязательно нужно кидаться ссылками на документацию и ворохом понтов?

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев, добавил пример

Comment: @Grundy спасибо большое!)